# Is there Downloads app on Android 11?

Tags: downloading, android-11, download-manager

I recently moved to Android 11 from Android 7 and noticed that there's no app that handles downloads, shows full list of files being downloaded, their size, estimated time etc.

Instead, all downloads shown in notifications from app **Download Manager**. But this notifications are very primitive, there are even no pause button only cancel button and progress bar. This app has no openable gui and shows only in notifications.

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: @MilesMorales CUBOT TAB 10